# EE1 to EE2 upgrade issues

Tags: ee1, ee2-upgrades

I'm trying to upgrade a site from EE1 to EE2 and I followed the EL docs to the letter but when I go to run the wizard I get "Click here to install a brand new copy of ExpressionEngine". Anyone know why this might be occurring?

UPDATE: Forgot to add that I would be upgrading an EE1.7.3 site to EE2.5.5 running on a MT GS server.

Comment: Stuart - does your config.php file have any conditional statements in it to determine the value of the array members? One common one is, for example, `$config['daylight_savings'] = (date('I') == 1) ? 'y ' : 'n';`. I've found in the past that statements like this in config.php trip-up the EE upgrader.

Comment: Nope. I've started adding that to my EE2 default config.php file I use but had never setup a master config like that for my EE1 sites or added anything on my own.

Comment: @StuartMcCoy, whatever happened with this?

Answer (score 2):

Stuart,

This usually indicates that EE is not finding your old EE 1 config.php.  [Step 4 of the upgrade instructions](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/upgrade_from_1.x.html#restore-some-1-x-files) has you placing your backed up EE 1 config.php in /system/expressionengine/config:

> Copy your old 1.x version of system/config.php to system/expressionengine/config/config.php

And that should help you to avoid this issue.  I know you said you're following the docs to the letter, but please do double check that your config.php in /system/expressionengine/config is the EE 1 config.  That should get you moving forward!

Comment: Yeah, I did that step. The only issue I might be having trouble with is the renaming of the system folder. I had renamed it previously and it's not clear that I need to rename it to "system_old" or "my_system_folder_name_old" and what happens to the new system folder. Does it need to stay "system" or does it need to be named after the older system folder? I've tried both approaches but nothing changes the fact that I'm getting the "install brand new site" instead of running the upgrade wizard.

Comment: Your old system folder should be renamed to anything.  _old is just a convention to let you know.  That's your backup, you see?  The new system folder can then most easily be renamed to whatever your system folder was before.

So if you had your EE 1 system folder of "enterhere", then you would rename it to "enterhere_old" and upload the EE 2 system folder as "enterhere".

Comment: That's what I thought but I had the same problem. I'll try from a fresh copy of the site and see what happens.

Comment: Started over with a fresh version of the EE1 site I'm updating. I renamed index.php and my_sys to index.php_old and my_sys_old. I copied over index.php, admin.php, system, and themes to the EE1 site. I renamed system to my_sys and updated index.php and admin.php to reflect the changed system folder name. I copied over config.php from my_sys_old to my_sys/expressionengin/config/config.php. I set file permissions for config.php and database.php to 666 and cache to 777. Ran the wizard by going to my_site/admin.php and once again I get the message to install a brand new site. #totally confused.

Comment: Something somewhere is pointing wrongly.  Is there a .htaccess redirect in place? Uh, I hate to suggest it but having done this - are you sure you're FTP'd to the right site? I'm hoping someone else has some other ideas here.

Comment: I removed the .htaccess file per another article I found online with the same issues. This is being done locally so I'm sure the files were moved to the right place. I'm in the process of setting up the site on another system and creating a dev site on their web host to try it there as well.

Comment: Still nothing. I tried this on another local system and a staging server on the host's site but I keep getting the same results every time.

Comment: I wish I had more to offer on this.  But I'm not sure why it would throw that error :(